# PHP OOP code to UML class diagram

Tags: php, class-diagram

I seek help in order to create a UML class diagram from this code.

I created a UML class diagram with the best of my knowledge, but weather if its correct or not, i dont know.

```
class driver {

    public function __contruct() {}

    public function theDriver($driveWhat) {

        switch($driveWhat) {

            case 1:
                $newCar = new car();
                $newCar->drive();
                break;
            case 2:
                $newTruck = new truck();
                $newTruck->drive();
                break;
            case 3:
                $newBike = new bike();
                $newBike->drive();
                break;
        }
    }
}

class car{function drive(){...}}
class truck{function drive(){...}}
class bike{function drive(){...}}
```

*My example of a UML class diagram that fits my example code*
[image]

Comment: have a look how strategy pattern is visualized. as example: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy -> it seems your idea is not that bad

Comment: I think i figured out that, the relation that im looking for is called Composition. And that relation is showed with a arrow with a diamond shape which is filled wiith the same color as the line.  However i would like some more feedback before i close this question.